# How to select those td in a table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've got a calendar in static html (example below) and I want to select whole week on hoover (just add '.active' class and on click it should return the first and last day of the week selected by clicking on it.

I think I should use .on() event, since it's dynamically loaded by a plugin.
I tried many jQuery selectors, but I can't find the proper one. Please, help me out, I'd like to learn how to do this in the best way :).

```
<div class="datepicker datepicker-dropdown dropdown-menu datepicker-orient-left datepicker-orient-top">
<div class="datepicker-days" style="display: block;">
<table class=" table-condensed">
<tbody>
   <tr>
      <td class="day active old">29</td>
      <td class="day old">30</td>
      <td class="day">1</td>
      <td class="day">2</td>
      <td class="day">3</td>
      <td class="day">4</td>
      <td class="day">5</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td class="day">6</td>
      <td class="day">7</td>
      <td class="day">8</td>
      <td class="day">9</td>
      <td class="day">10</td>
      <td class="day">11</td>
      <td class="day">12</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td class="day">13</td>
      <td class="day">14</td>
      <td class="day">15</td>
      <td class="day">16</td>
      <td class="day">17</td>
      <td class="day">18</td>
      <td class="day">19</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td class="day">20</td>
      <td class="day">21</td>
      <td class="day">22</td>
      <td class="day">23</td>
      <td class="day">24</td>
      <td class="day">25</td>
      <td class="day">26</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td class="day">27</td>
      <td class="day">28</td>
      <td class="day">29</td>
      <td class="day">30</td>
      <td class="day">31</td>
      <td class="day new">1</td>
      <td class="day new">2</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td class="day new">3</td>
      <td class="day new">4</td>
      <td class="day new">5</td>
      <td class="day new">6</td>
      <td class="day new">7</td>
      <td class="day new">8</td>
      <td class="day new">9</td>
   </tr>
</tbody>
</div></div>
```

Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

**JQuery:**

If you want to add `class` on click

```
$(document).on('click', 'tr', function () {
    $('.active').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active')
});
```

If you want it to add `class` on hover

```
$(document).on('mouseover', 'tr', function () {
    $('.active').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active')
});
```

**CSS:**

```
.active{
    color:red;
}
```

**[JSFiddle Demo - onClick](http://jsfiddle.net/erv4r/9/)**

**[JSFiddle Demo - Hover](http://jsfiddle.net/erv4r/10/)**

Comment: *"I think I should use .on() event, **since it's dynamically loaded** by a plugin"* This jQuery doesn't account for that, otherwise a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that you're looking for something like this.

```
$(document).on("click", "td", function(event){

\\your code here

});
```

Comment: yes, I can write something like this ;) I need a deeper implementation ,since I need to select whole weeks (so it means all I need to add class '.active. to all td in the hovered week).

Answer (score 0):

Whole weeks are quite simple. When you click a `td` look within it's parent

```
$(document).on('click', 'td.day', function () {    
    $('.selected').removeClass('selected');/* clear previous class clicks*/
    $(this).parent().children().addClass('selected');  
});
```

For hover use something like:

```
$(document).on('mouseenter mouseleave', 'tr', function () { 
     $(this).toggleClass('rowHoverClass');
})
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/v3M3Q/)**</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for something like this:

```
$(document).on("click", "tr", function() {
    $(this).addClass("active");
    var first_day = $(this).find("td").first();
    var last_day = $(this).find("td").last();
    console.log(first_day, last_day);
});
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/x5Af9/